# Dynamic sitemap for NextJs 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, seo, sitemap, next.js13

I am following this guide to create a dynamic sitemap for NextJs 13.4.6 https://claritydev.net/blog/nextjs-dynamic-sitemap-pages-app-directory

The issue I am having is the bottom of the article is where it has the code to do with a sitemap for NextJS versions of 13.3 and above - however, it does not work.

This is the code for my sitemap to return an object of URLs based on my routes and blog posts from cms (I am getting the blog post data from our API).

```
interface ApiResponseEntries {
  data: TransformedEntry[];
  status: number;
}

// This will change when we have a production URL
const rootUrl = "http://localhost:3000";

export default async function sitemap() {
  try {
    const url = "/api/routes/contentful/entries";

    const response: AxiosResponse<ApiResponseEntries> = await axios.get(url);

    const blogPostEntries: TransformedEntry[] = response.data.map(
      (entry: TransformedEntry) => {
        return entry.contentType === "blogPost";
      }
    );

    const blogPosts = blogPostEntries.map((entry: TransformedEntry) => ({
      url: `${URL}/blog/${entry.id}`,
      lastModified: entry.updatedAt,
    }));

    const routes = ["/", "/blog"].map((route) => ({
      url: `${URL}${route}`,
      lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
    }));

    return [...routes, ...blogPosts];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error", error);
  }
}
```

The issue is unless I read the article wrong I do not understand how this is providing a sitemap for Google if I go to localhost:3000/sitemap.xml there is just a 404 page... which makes sense as I never anywhere defined anything being XML.

Does anyone know how for the newer version of NextJs13 to get this dynamic sitemap to return on that url endpoint? or can point to examples of how it's been done.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/sitemap) on this matter, rather than a 3rd party article.

Comment: Nextjs 13 documentation tells us how to build sitemap dynamically at "BUILD" time but it does not tell it how to revalidate the sitemap.xml when we need to.  So the question is how do we rebuild or the sitemap when we add a new blog post without having to rebuild the website.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `URL` with the const `rootUrl`.

```
const rootUrl = "http://localhost:3000"

const blogPosts = blogPostEntries.map((entry: TransformedEntry) => ({
      url: `${rootUrl}/blog/${entry.id}`,
      lastModified: entry.updatedAt,
    }))

const routes = ["/", "/blog"].map((route) => ({
      url: `${rootUrl}${route}`,
      lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
    }));

return [...routes, ...blogPosts];
```

let me now if it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?  Please share your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sitemap.ts` file should be in the `app` directory.

Then you have to build the app.

```
npm run build
```

and then run

```
npm run start
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue until I realized that it was that I had a basePath set in the next.config.js and I was not using that in my request.  So I found that after I fixed my request url to include the basePath, the sitemap generation function worked to serve at /{basePath}/sitemap.xml and it was dynamic after launch, e.g. I didn't have to worry about it only regenerating at build time.